# cURL extracts the wrong hyperlink from a webpage in bash

Tags: jquery, json, bash, curl, air

I am trying to use cURL to extract an hyperlink from Adobe:

- The website is https://get.adobe.com/air/
- The link is
  https://get.adobe.com/air/download/?installer=Adobe_AIR_22.0_for_Win32&standalone=1
  [image]

When using cURL command line, the link that I get is a default one "http://www.adobe.com" instead of the one above.
I suspect that cURL is not "calling" the JavaScript or JQuery that populate the button with the right hyperlink.

[image]

Can anyone please point me to the right direction ?
How can I get cURL to generate or extract the right link for this button ?

Comment: If it's not javascript it might still be some kind of 3xx Redirect code that the server sends, and you could check cURL cmdline options to make it follow a redirect.

Comment: This isn't a redirect thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/).

Create a script like this

```
#! /usr/bin/phantomjs --ssl-protocol=any
var page = require('webpage').create(),
  system = require('system'),
  t, address;

if (system.args.length === 1) {
  console.log('Usage: load.js <some URL>');
  phantom.exit();
}

page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36';
address = system.args[1];
page.open(address, function(status) {
  if (status !== 'success') {
    console.log('FAIL to load the address: ' + status);
  } else {
    var btn = page.content.match(/<a id="buttonDownload" .*download-button">/)
    console.log(btn);
  }
  phantom.exit();
});
```

and invoke it like (if your OS supports shebang)

```
$ ./load.js https://get.adobe.com/air
```

obtaining

```
<a id="buttonDownload" href="/air/download/?installer=Adobe_AIR_22.0_for_Win32&amp;standalone=1" class="Button ButtonYellow download-button">
```

Otherwise, use it as

```
phantomjs --ssl-protocol=any load.js https://get.adobe.com/air
```

Answer (score 0):

`cURL` just executes an HTTP/S request.  The HTTP protocol is just for text, and when HTML is returned, that text can include tags that browsers and other tools can interpret, notably `<img>`, `<link>`, and `<script>`.

So the text you get back is just that; actually executing the javascript in the same way that a browser does involves a great deal (understatement) of work.

Tools such as Selenium provide programatic mechanisms to "execute" the HTML of a modern web page.  Might want to look there.